# Multiple instances of deepstream.io server inside one node

Tags: deepstream.io

Is it possible to run multiple instances of the deepstream.io server inside one node (computer)?
Each instance will listen on different port, store in different storage, etc.
Use case is when one instance is used for the production and other for the staging - production and staging use different MongoDB databases for storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, just make sure to point them to two different configuration files when starting. Here's how it would work on e.g. AWS Linux:

Install deepstream

```
sudo wget https://bintray.com/deepstreamio/rpm/rpm -O /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-deepstreamio-rpm.repo
sudo yum install -y deepstream.io
```

Copy the permission file and two versions of the config file

```
cp /etc/deepstream/config.yml config-dev.yml
cp /etc/deepstream/config.yml config-prod.yml
cp /etc/deepstream/permissions.yml permissions.yml
```

Change the ports (and anything else you'd need) in the config file

[image: vim config]

and then start both with

```
 deepstream start -c config-dev.yml
 deepstream start -c config-prod.yml
```

resulting in

[image]

To better handle multiple deepstream processes running on the same machine, I'd recommend using a tool like [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Its node-based, so you'd install it on AWS via

```
 curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo bash -
 sudo yum -y install nodejs
 sudo npm install -g pm2
```

Now you can run multiple processes with different configurations as follows

```
pm2 start --name ds-dev deepstream -- start -c ~/config-dev.yml
pm2 start --name ds-prod deepstream -- start -c ~/config-prod.yml
```

resulting in

[image: PM2 output]

PM2 allows you to easily start / end / restart / monitor individual processes using their IDs, e.g. `pm2 stop 0` and keeps track of your logs, restarts processes etc...

Comment: How to stop specific instance? If I run "deepstream stop" it will just stop the instance started later.

Comment: I've added an example using PM2 that should address this